# Tracking Woocommerce Add to Cart

Tags: php, woocommerce, tracking, cart

I am looking for a way to track add to cart event in woocommerce, push the data on a few datalayers (product name, quantity, price and sku) so I can track them in google tag manager. We are pretty new on php and I cannot seem to find any example online. Could you suggest a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I've come up with a couple of options.

## Option #1

This is not a very clean approach, but should work without much trouble. The idea is to bind the `.single_add_to_cart_button` to perform an AJAX request so you can transfer all the visible data in the product page to a PHP array.

Add this JS to the product page:

```
jQuery( '.single_add_to_cart_button' ).click( function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'get_add_to_cart_data',
            sku: jQuery( '...' ) // extract the data you want from the page
        }
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log( response ); // log errors
            jQuery( '.single_add_to_cart_button' ).unbind( 'click' ).click(); // now add to cart
        }
    });
});
```

Then, as server-side PHP:

```
function get_add_to_cart_data() {
    $sku = $_POST['sku']; // all your data will be in this array
    track(); // do whatever to track the data
    echo "Success";
}
// Now bind this function to use with AJAX in WordPress
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_add_to_cart_data', 'get_add_to_cart_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_add_to_cart_data', 'get_add_to_cart_data' );
```

## Option #2

I prefer this idea, but I haven't fully tested it. You'll be using the [`woocommerce_add_cart_item`](http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/2.4.9/filters/woocommerce_add_cart_item/) filter, with something like the following in PHP:

```
function track_cart_item( $cart_array ) {
    track( $cart_array ); // this array should contain most (all?) the data you want to use
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item', 'track_cart_item', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an short tutorial article that covers up the subject:

[sampovirmasalo.fi - Track Add to Cart events in WooCommerce with this Google Tag Manager code snippet](https://sampovirmasalo.fi/tracking-add-to-cart-conversions-with-google-analytics-a-comprehensive-code-snippet-for-e-commerce-websites/)

The basic idea is to add tracking events for add to cart button on single product page and add to cart link button in product listings and carousels. It's also necessary to handle the ajax and non-ajax ways separately.